# H2: how to tell if index exists?

Tags: java, sql, h2

I can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to create a table only if it doesn't exist.

How can i do the same for `CREATE INDEX..` to only create it if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it as follows,

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS NEW_INDEX_NAME ON TABLE_NAME;
```

You can follow link aswell,
http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_index

Answer (score 0):

You could remove it if it exists.

> DROP INDEX IF EXISTS IDXNAME

Then just add it afterward.

```
CREATE INDEX IDXNAME ON TEST(NAME)
```

I found it here [H2 grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#drop_index)